# How do I access a value from a json object in my view (html page) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my controller class I am getting a json response from my model and I want to show only a specific value from the result array in my view. How can I do that?

In my view I tried

```
<h4><%= @info[:result][-1] %></h4>
=> TypeError in Users#create
   no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

<h4><%= @info['result'][-1] %></h4>
=> t 
this t is the last letter from 'result'

<h4><%= json: @info[:result][-1] %></h4>
=> Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check <h4><%= json: @info[:result][-1] %></h4>
```

My response.body which is stored in the @info instance is:

```
{"result":[{"id":"3","username":"Sam","password":"111"},{"id":"4","username":"Harshal","password":"1234"},{"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"}]}
```

My expected output is:

```
{"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"}
or
"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"
```

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of the code where you assign `@info` because according to the error it looks like an array not a hash!

Comment: Your `@info` is a `Hash` having `result` as key and array values. You should access first element of array by `@info[:result][0]` or if you want to `puts` it out `@info[:result].map{ |element| puts element }`.

Comment: @kunashir I figured that while I was performing actions that should be done on a hash in rails i.e. '=>' . I was doing it on json response which is of type ':' . All I needed was to JSON.parse(response.body, :symbolize_names => true) and it worked. JSON.parse() converted my {"result":[{"id":"3",...},{"id":"4",...}...}] response to {:result=>[{:id=>"3",...},{:id=>"4",...}...}] format which enabled me to access it in the view as I would in the controller.